# Why is Spring MVC inserting an empty object into what should be an empty list?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm uploading multiple files. This works fine when I actually select files to upload; they get into their List just fine, but when I click Upload without selecting a file, instead of getting an empty List, I get a List with an empty file in it. My validator is checking for the size of this List being 0, so it sneaks past it.

Yes, I can work around it and just check for an empty file, and yes I can disable the upload button when no file is selected, but I want to know why Spring does this and possibly how to stop it from doing it.

Here's the jsp:

```
<form:form commandName="documentsBean" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="submittedFormAction" value="attachDocumentSave"/>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="attachFiles" multiple/>
    <button type="submit">Attach</button>
</form:form>
```

The bean, nothing fancy here:

```
public class DocumentsBean
{
    private List<MultipartFile> files;
    public List<MultipartFile> getFiles(){
        return files;
    }
    public void setFiles(List<MultipartFile> files){
        this.files = files;
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "submittedFormAction=attachDocumentSave" })
public ModelAndView attachDocumentSave(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("documentsBean") DocumentsBean documentsBean, BindingResult errors) throws Exception
{
    // At this point documentsBean.files is an ArrayList<E> with size = 1
}
```

When I drill down into `documentsBean.files`, I see `elementData[0]` is a `CommonsMultipartFile`, its fileName is an empty string and its size is 0.

What is going on?

Comment: That is probably because the "part" named "file" is being sent in the request with no filename or length. So basically it's an empty file like you're seeing in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your solution. The explanation is below.

Add an [`@InitBinder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html) method that sets the following property. Ideally you would add it to a [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) class, but the controller with the corresponding `@RequestMapping` method works as well.

```
@InitBinder
public void init(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setBindEmptyMultipartFiles(false);
}
```

You'll also need to change your `DocumentsBean` class like so

```
private List<MultipartFile> files = Arrays.asList();
```

So that the field isn't `null`.

Spring uses a [`ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html) to generate an argument for a `@ModelAttribute` annotated parameter like yours

```
@ModelAttribute("documentsBean") DocumentsBean documentsBean
```

This [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) uses the request (and its form parameters) to generate an instance of whatever type your parameter is, by binding parameters to the instance class' 
instance fields. If it detects that the request has a content type of `multipart/form-data`, it will perform special binding.

This binding is done in [`WebDataBinder#bindMultipart(..)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html#bindMultipart-java.util.Map-org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues-). It retrieves all the `MultipartFile` objects created by the `MulitpartResolver`. If there is only one, it checks two things.

```
if (isBindEmptyMultipartFiles() || !value.isEmpty()) {
    mpvs.add(key, value);
}
```

The first method call

> Return[s] whether to bind empty `MultipartFile` parameters.

and the second checks if the `MultipartFile` has any body content or not. It won't if you submitted the form without selecting a file (or if you selected an empty file AFAIK).

If either of those expressions resolve to `true`, then Spring will provide your handler method with this empty `MultipartFile` holder. Otherwise, it will not bind that field, which is why you want a default value (so it doesn't remain `null`)

```
private List<MultipartFile> files = Arrays.asList();
```

Take a look at the javadoc of [`WebDataBinder#setBindEmptyMultipartFiles(boolean)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html#setBindEmptyMultipartFiles-boolean-) which states

> Set whether to bind empty MultipartFile parameters. Default is "true".
>
> Turn this off if you want to keep an already bound MultipartFile when
>   the user resubmits the form without choosing a different file. Else,
>   the already bound MultipartFile will be replaced by an empty
>   MultipartFile holder.

This is the property you should set to `false` in the `@InitBinder` method shown above.

Comment: Hello, I have a similar issue and I've done exactly as you suggested but it doesn't solve my problem. It works for single field of type MultipartFile but it doesn't work for List<MulitpartFile>. The only difference in my code is that I have 5 different inputs in html that are bound to 1 list. So even if I specify @InitBinder method, and leave all 5 inputs empty, I'm still getting a list of size 5 with empty files. Any idea where could be the problem? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: @Sikor It's difficult to tell just from that description. I'd suggest asking a new questions with all the details necessary to reproduce the issue.